# Scrapy: modifying an Xpath for items that appear only in some pages

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I built a `scrapy` crawler and for a series of pages that hold their information in a repeating pattern of stacking tr and td tags.

The basic XPath for them is

```
/div/table/tr[5]/td/table/tr/td/table[1]/tr[/*number*/]/td[2]/strong/text()
```

where `/*number*/` is an integer I use to distinguish each separate field I want to extract. The Name of the item, for example, is always at 1, website at 3, email at 7, and so on where `ContactEmail` is the last of the tr tags I need - but not the last in the range. so I just used the XPath with an extract method to get each value and add it to my item object - but I found that some of the pages have an optional `ContactPosition` field that only appears in some of the items and is always at an index before `ContactEmail`. In the examples I saw `ContactEmail` would be at index 13 in all cases save for those with a `ContactPosition` value where it would be moved to index 14.

Is there any way to check how many tr tags there are so I can do an if-else to assign the right index number and avoid an index out of bounds exception?

@tdelaney:

The tags on a page with both read like this.

```
                <tr>
                    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">Position:</td>
                    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo"><strong>General Manager</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">Email:</td>
                    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo"><strong>samir@philka.com</strong></td>
                </tr>
```

I thought about doing that but 
1) The ContactPosition tag would be missing in pages without a CP so wouldn't using it give an error?
2) Every page has two emails but the tags for both emails are identical and the only distinction between them is that one is fixed at the 5th tr tag and the other (which I call ContactEmail) can be on the 13th or 14th, so using the email tag for identifying would not work well.

Comment: Is there something uniquely identifying in the first column so that instead of `...tr[/*number*/]/td[2]...` you could do `...tr[td[1]/text()='Contact Email']/td[2]...`?

Comment: use `[last()]` index to take Email. `/div/table/tr[5]/td/table/tr/td/table[1]/tr[last()]/td[2]/strong/text()`

Comment: This should work but I wouldn't be able to get the ContactPosition...

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work. I was wrong, email is not the last tr tag, it's just the last one I need...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`(your/xpath/here)[last()]`** pattern to get the last matched element of the entire XML document. Combine that with what suggested by [**@tdelaney**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) in comment, which is to identify the target `tr` by content of the first `td` element, and you will have something like this :

```
(//table/tr[td='Email:']/td[2]/text())[last()]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6d130eff57590d8f9c71bd8efc01ce5d)</kbd>**

**Test XML :**

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">Email:</td>  
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">
      <strong>someotheremail@gmail.com</strong>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">Position:</td>  
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">
      <strong>General Manager</strong>
    </td> 
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">Email:</td>  
    <td class="cont_1col_txt_cuerpo">
      <strong>samir@philka.com</strong>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

**Output :**

```
samir@philka.com
```